# Externally external commenting system

Tags: web-apps, comment-system

The external commenting system, such as Disqus, is embedded in the website that installs it, but I do not want to embed anything.

I want the visitor to click on a link which leads to the system (outside of my website), and the system will create a discussion thread, if not already created, according to HTTP referrer or an identifier, such as web page URL. The visitor then can discuss about the page there.

The only requirement I need is

- Not to be embedded in the website

I know this sounds very weird to have comments on external website rather than being embedded in page, I just don't want to include additional HTML/JavaScript/CSS into my pages, but still to allow visitors a place to discuss.

Comment: I suppose it has to be hosted? Or would you be fine with self-hosting it?

Comment: @unor I would take anything as long as it's *not* embedded into the page.

Comment: This allows spam if no other control is placed. I can simply specify the referrer header with cURL. I can easily create a thread without an actual original page.